# JPA Update an Entity in a different transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE Datastore JPA 2.0 (on Dev Server)

The question is very very simple. How do I update an Entity, that is already in the Datastore and persistent from a Transaction and Entity Manager instance different that the one that fetched it.

For instance, a User Entity that was serialized as an Attribute in a session, the transaction that fetched it has been long closed and gone, it has just been modified.
Persisting the entity gives an error saying that the entity is already persistent.
merging it, doesnt produce an error, but it gives a warning saying that the transaction wasnt committed or rolled back, and rolls back the transaction, although I explicitly commit and close right after the merge. Dont know whats going on here ! The thing that is really annoying is that other Entities update normally no problem ... is that a dev server bug ?? (Also lots of funny stuff happens with Namespaces, entities ending up in the Empty Namespace, when they shouldnt) Please help !

Exact Case:

```
EntityManager em = EMF.get().createEntityManager();
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.merge(MyInstance);
//MyInstance is an entity that is already persistent, modified its datastore value, currently 
//dettached and I would very much like to update the datastore record to its value
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
```

Results in:

```
Sep 10, 2014 3:38:11 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilterhandleAbandonedTxns
WARNING: Request completed without committing or rolling back transaction with id 2.Transaction will be rolled back.
```

Comment: Maybe you have optimistic locking (aka version control)?

Comment: No I dont have any locking ... even so, that is on the dev server ... there isnt any other Servelet Instances fighting for reads other than the one I am running ... no race conditions here ... I even ran the code synchronized to avoid any potential problems from mulch-threaded processing ... same thing

Comment: Could you post a full stack of the error? maybe turn the debug mode?